# PK string returns in Spring response

Tags: java, spring-boot, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to return custom error message by using @ExceptionHandler but I receive extra junk value of PK in the response. I have attached the screen shot as well as code here in for any suggestion.

Anyone can suggest here?

Java Code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = InvalidMediaPKException.class)
public ResponseEntity<MediaErrorWsDTO> handleInvalidMediaPKException(final InvalidMediaPKException exception)
{
    final MediaErrorWsDTO errors = new MediaErrorWsDTO();
    errors.setCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
    errors.setMessage(String.format(INVALID_MEDIA_ERROR_MSG));
    return new ResponseEntity<MediaErrorWsDTO>(errors, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does MediaErrorWsDTO look like?

Comment: @EssexBoy - I have taken two String attributes  code and message.

Comment: `public class MediaErrorWsDTO implements Serializable
{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private String code;
 private String message;
 public MediaErrorWsDTO()
 {
  // default constructor
 }
 public void setCode(final String code)
 {
  this.code = code;
 }
 public String getCode()
 {
  return code;
 }
 public void setMessage(final String message)
 {
  this.message = message;
 }
 public String getMessage()
 {
  return message;
 }
}`

Comment: It looks like a ZIP file header to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MediaErrorWsDTO implements Serializable
{
// some code
}
```

I got issue resolved after adding `@XmlRootElement` on  `MediaErrorWsDTO`  class.